# where clause while joining select

Tags: mysql, join

I need to get payment sum for all period and for current month. There are two tables: category and transactions.

transactions:

```
id  int(11)                         
category    varchar(32)                          
dttm_added  datetime                    
minus   float               
minus_currency  varchar(32)
```

categories:

```
id  int(11)                 
key varchar(32)                          
name    varchar(50)                          
type    varchar(1)
```

Here is my query:

```
select  `key`, `id`, `name`, minus_month,month_cur
                                from `categories` as ct

                                left join (
                                select  `category` as tr_ct_m, date_format(`dttm_trans`, '%Y%m') as dat, sum(`minus`) as minus_month, `minus_currency` as month_cur from `transactions`  where dat = date_format(now(), '%Y%m')
                                ) as tr_m on tr_m.tr_ct_m = ct.key 
                                where `type` = '-'
```

I need to check clause in select before joining, because after sum  of minus_month all dates are turning to Null.
Help plz

Comment: provide the schema  of tables.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand you correctly,please try below:

```
select  `ct`.`key`, `ct`.`id`, `ct`.`name`, tr_m.minus_month,tr_m.month_cur from 
 ( select *   from `categories` where `type` = '-') as ct
left join 
 ( select  `category` as tr_ct_m, date_format(`dttm_trans`, '%Y%m') as dat, 
     sum(`minus`) as minus_month, `minus_currency` as month_cur from `transactions`  
     where dat = date_format(now(), '%Y%m')
 ) as tr_m on tr_m.tr_ct_m = ct.key
```

Comment: yes, my english is bad, so i'll try explain my problem again. Where clause  cant be used in 'inner join'. All conditions can be used only after selecting, when i need to make condition in select before joining